# how to use delegate to pass data to from one View Controller to another?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, uitableview, delegates

Im trying to pass data from one View controller to another using a delegate

right now im struggling to pass data from the CartVC to ModifyVC when pressing the modifyButton in the CartCell. This is modeled similar to a previous question that I asked before(see link below). Im just struggling to pass data to the ModifyVC since I keep getting an error saying *Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value* and closes out the simulator

the modifybtn passes cell data for the cel that is selected in the CartVC

I dont want to use didSelectRowAt to pass the cell data since im using the modifyBtn in the CartCell to pass the data using the ModifyDelegate

I know that im close to my solution to making this work. Im just getting that one error that is preventing me from passing the data to the ModifyVC

[How pass data from button in TableViewCell to View Controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58279448/how-pass-data-from-button-in-tableviewcell-to-view-controller)

```
class CartViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{

    var selectedProduct: Items!
    var modifyItems: Cart?

    var cart: [Cart] = []
    var groupedItems: [String: [Cart]] = [:]
    var brands: [String] = []

    @IBOutlet weak var cartTableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) { //segue code for delegate
        if let vc = segue.destination as? ModifyViewController {
            vc.modifyItems = self.modifyItems
        }
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return brands.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        let brand = brands[section]
        return groupedCartItems[brand]!.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cartCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CartCell") as! CartCell

        let brand = brands[indexPath.section]
        let itemsToDisplay = groupedItems[brand]![indexPath.row]
        cartCell.configure(withCartItems: itemsToDisplay.cart)
        cartCell.modifyDelegate = self
        cartCell.modifyItems = self.modifyItems

        return cartCell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let cartHeader = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CartHeader") as! CartHeader        
        let headerTitle = brands[section]
        cartHeader.brandName.text = "Brand: \(headerTitle)"        
        return cartHeader
    }    
}
```

---

```
class ModifyViewController: UIViewController {

    private var counterValue = 1
    var lastSelectedWeightButton = RoundButton()
    var modifyItems: Cart!

    @IBOutlet weak var price1: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var price2: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var price3: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var weight1: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var weight2: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var weight3: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
        formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
        price1.text = "$\(formatter.string(for: modifyItems.cart.price1)!)" // getting the error right here that causes the simulator to close out and prevents me from viewing the modify VC
        price2.text = "$\(formatter.string(for: modifyItems.cart.price2)!)"
        price3.text = "$\(formatter.string(for: modifyItems.cart.price3)!)"
        weight1.text = modifyItems.cart.weight1
        weight2.text = modifyItems.cart.weight2
        weight3.text = modifyItems.cart.weight3

    }
}
```

side note: The CartVC cells data is populated from the HomeVc when an item is selected it posted as a cell in the CartVC. the Items class populates the cells in the HomeVC.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing Data between View Controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers)

Comment: @Magnas, that answer doesn't work for my solution, since most my data is being retrieved from cloud Firestore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update following line in cellForRowAt function:

```
cartCell.modifyItems = self.modifyItems
```

to this:

```
cartCell.modifyItems = itemsToDisplay
```

Comment: just ran it, it didn't work and im still getting the error in the same location

Comment: On which line you are getting this error? Which optional value you are trying to unwrap?

Comment: in my ModifyVC ```price1.text = "$\(formatter.string(for: modifyItems.cart.price1)!)"``` that crashes the simulator once I press the modifyBtn

Comment: Add this `cartCell.modifyItems = self.modifyItems;` in `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)`

Comment: still getting the same results :( could it something else that could be causing the error in the in ModifyVC that's leads to the crash of the simulator

Comment: No actually I think that if you add a break point in `prepareForSegue` you will see that `self.modifyItems` is not initialized before calling `performSegue`.

Comment: Update `cartCell.modifyItems = self.modifyItems` to `cartCell.modifyItems = itemsToDisplay`

Comment: Glad to be of help.